# Motivation for Smoothness and Regularity of Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm looking for motivation for the property of smoothness (of morphisms) and regularity (of objects) in algebraic geometry, from an algebraic viewpoint.

I understand that requiring this makes the scheme closer to a smooth manifold.

But what properties do regular schemes have that ordinary ones do not? Do smooth schemes enjoy any morphism-factorization properties? Is there a universal property related to these?

Comment: Maybe if $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$ then $X$ being regular as an affine scheme is equivalent to $R$ being Noetherian and each $R_f$ being regular as a ring? I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: There is something called formally smoothness which is characterized by a lifting property. See i.e. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ